# How should I make a route for each page in Laravel5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im new to L5 and here, stackoverflow.
I'm making a Blog service based on Repository pattern.
Now I've made some Service class(like ImageService, PostService, CommentService...) and Repositories as data access object.

From now, I will make views. First, "Top page" I would like to.
Need to inject 2 Service class. "ImageService(allUsersImages)", "PostService(allUsersPosts)".

I am stopping here....bothering what the best way.
please let me know if my thought is good, or is there any way?

```
1.Creating Controller

class IndexController　extends Controller
{
    public function top(ImageRepository $image, PostRepository $post)
    {
        $images= $image->allUsersImages();
        $posts= $post->allUsersPosts();

        return view('/index')
                 ->with('images', $images)
                 ->with('posts', $posts);
    }

    public function mypage(ImageRepository $image, 
                           PostRepository $post, $id)
    {
        $images= $image->allUsersImagesById($id);
        $posts= $post->allUsersPosts($id);

        return view('/index')
                 ->with('images', $images)
                 ->with('posts', $posts);
    }
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
                   prepare methods for each page

    }

2. Creating routing

    Route::get('/top', 'IndexController@top');
    Route::get('/mypage', 'IndexController@mypage');
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

Comment: If your repository is registered within container, you can feed it on constructor. Store it on class property. Call it on any method. This snippet on docs is really showing you how to do it https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well** i think what you already doing is also pretty good.

```
class IndexController　extends Controller
{
    public function top(ImageRepository $image, PostRepository $post)
    { }
}
```

When you write something like this, `Laravel Dependancy Manager` will inject `ImageRepository` and `PostRepository` for you  to the `function top() {}`

Now your question is is there any a better approach then this ?

**IMHO:**
You don't need to ask the dependancy manager to do this work for you.
Just Use the `ImageRepository` and `PostRepository` in the function like this.

```
    class IndexController　extends Controller
    {
        public function top()
        {
              $image_repository = new ImageRepository(); 
              $post_repository = new PostRepository();
        }
    }
```

Now what i understand is `ImageRepository` and `PostRepository` are your `DAL(Data Access Layer)` or maybe a wrapper around your `ORM (Models)`, then why using a wrapper around Models, why not using directly models, Since you don't have methods sharing the repository in single page accesss. Just invoke the models directly. These are safe and common practice in laravel.